# Actioning CRON with PHP from a MYSQL QUERY

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, cron

Ok so here is my situation, I have a PHP file that is set to execute through CRONJOBS/Tab at 10:30pm every night,

```
<?php
include ("db_connection.php");
{
mysqli_query("UPDATE members SET status='ASHORE' ");
}
echo "<img src='system/images/correct.svg' alt='' height='150px' width='150px'/>";
?>
```

What i would like to do is only allow the php script above to run if certain conditions in another DB table is met.

```
mysqli_query("SELECT id='1' FROM system WHERE monday_ashore='Yes' ");
```

Ive tried UNION, JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN etc, but i don't seem to be getting anywhere.

This is an example of what i have tried so far:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE members SET status='ASHORE' ");
UNION
("SELECT id='1' FROM system WHERE monday_ashore='Yes'");
```

and

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE members SET status='ASHORE' ");
UNION
("SELECT * FROM system WHERE monday_ashore='Yes' AND id='1'");
```

If the monday_ashore='Yes' then the Cron will Execute, if it is NO, it will NOT Execute.

In the DB, there is only 1 Record/Row in the System Table, and Multiple Records/Rows in the Members Table. When it executes correctly it should UPDATE ALL members ASHORE if monday_ashore is YES. and do nothing if NO.

I need to set this situation up for each day of the week. to execute at around 10:30pm or even midnight.  I can set up the Cron no problem, its getting the MySql Query to execute correctly. Any help or advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with a query like this. It stores the new or the old value in status

```
UPDATE members SET `status`=
IF( (SELECT monday_ashore FROM system WHERE  id='1') = "yes", 'ASHORE' , `status`);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> select * from members;
+----+---------+
| id | status  |
+----+---------+
|  1 | status1 |
|  2 | status2 |
+----+---------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from system;
+----+---------------+
| id | monday_ashore |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | no            |
+----+---------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE members SET `status`=
    -> IF( (SELECT monday_ashore FROM system WHERE  id='1') = "yes", 'ASHORE' , `status`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from members;
+----+---------+
| id | status  |
+----+---------+
|  1 | status1 |
|  2 | status2 |
+----+---------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> update system set monday_ashore='Yes';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE members SET `status`= IF( (SELECT monday_ashore FROM system WHERE  id='1') = "yes", 'ASHORE' , `status`);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0,00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from members;
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
|  1 | ASHORE |
|  2 | ASHORE |
+----+--------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I get a Syntax error with the above suggestion. Ive run it through an SQL checker it shows errors, and also i get a blank page when i execute the SQL in the PHP page.

Comment: @Mark Rhodes - sorry, cut and paste error, my mistake. the ) was at the wrong place. can you try it again please

Comment: ok, so I've tried your update to the code, and it is still not working correctly.  Here is what i have, the full code that I'm using:    `code`<?php
include ("../config/db_connect.php");
{
mysqli_query("UPDATE members SET 'status'=
IF( (SELECT monday_ashore FROM system WHERE id='1') = 'Yes' , 'ASHORE' , 'status'");
$result = mysqli_query($query);
   if($result)
   {
       echo '
    SUCCESS
    ';
   }else{
       echo '
    ERROR
    ';
   }
}
?>`code`

Comment: have you turned BACKTICKS OR TICKS around **'status'** . You must use backticks in mysql for use keywords as fieldnames

Comment: Ive tried it both ways.    `code`mysqli_query("UPDATE members SET `status`=
if ( (SELECT monday_ashore FROM system WHERE id='1') = 'Yes' , 'ASHORE' , ` status`");`code`              If i leave the "Yes" with the double quotes i get an error, so have to change these to single quotes to not get an error.

Comment: im not to sure how to add the code tags properly to be able to show you the code in a comment.

Comment: Right, you help DOES work if i do it through phpmyadmin SQL, but not as a PHP script. So thank you for that. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can have a first SQL SELECT that gets the value of the monday_ashore column in the database :

```
SELECT monday_ashore from system where id='1';
```

Then, test this value in PHP and, depending on the result, execute the query updating the users.

In order to test the value of monday_ashore in PHP, you can use the function [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) for example.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to run the query

```
"SELECT id='1' FROM system WHERE monday_ashore='Yes' "
```

and check the result before executing the rest of the code in PHP. Check the result and if it satisfy then go ahead else exit.